# Как с помощью рекурсии получить сумму элементов массива?

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Вывод элементов массива я реализовал, и то не факт что правильно, но работает, счётчик итерации внутри метода не работал, пришлось его засунуть в аргументы.

```
static void recurs(int[] mass,int value = 0)
     {
        
         
        if(value >= mass.Length)
         return;     
         Console.Write(mass[value] + " ");
            
         value++;        
         
       recurs(mass,value); 
     
     
     }
```

Но кое как вывел, по этому принципу пытался сложить элементы для общей суммы. Но вообще не получается (
И такой вопрос, можно ли объявлять переменные, которые будут отвечать за счётчик в теле рекурс метода или они должны быть объявил в аргументах?
А это вот нерабочий код для подсчёта суммы(

```
static void Summ(int[] mass,int a = 0,int summ = 0)
     {
        if(a >= mass.Length)
         return;     
         summ =+ mass[a];
         Console.Write(summ + " "); 
         a++;        
         
       Summ(mass,a,summ);
         
         
         
     }
```

Comment: Вы забываете про то, что методы могут возвращать результат. То есть сумма, это условно `int Sum(int[] array, int index) => array[index] + Sum(array, index +1);` (проверки на пустоту и так далее опустил для простоты). И да, научитесь давать осмысленные имена, вот что такое `a`? Не сокращайте, не пишите русскими, не пишите одну букву, не ленитесь в конце концов, именование очень важно в программировании! Даже если это черновик.

Comment: Да мне без return надо реализовать, return я должен использовать только для выхода из рекурсии.

Comment: @gachi_muchenik, ты неправильно понимаешь, как работает рекусия

Comment: так return и сработает, когда выражение вычислится полностью, мало того, без него рекурсии толковой не получится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так решение будет выглядеть

```
static int Sum(int[] array, int index = 0)
{
    if (index >= array.Length)
        return 0;
    return array[index] + Sum(array, index + 1);
}
```

вызов будет выглядеть так

```
int sum = Sum(array);
```

Comment: Не особо понял данную строку return array[index] + Summ(arr, index+1);Мы возвращаем элемент массива со сложенном в будущем возвращаем значением?Просто первый раз такое возвращение вижу. Мы возвращаем сумму элемента и возвращаем ого в будущем элемента это как

Comment: @gachi_muchenik чтобы вычислилось значение сложения, нужен элемент по индексу и результат вызова этой же функции для следующего элемента. То есть результат сложения вычислится и вернется, когда обе его половинки будут вычислены. Можно было бы написать `int result = array[index] + Sum(array, index + 1); return result;` если вам так проще понять.

Comment: @gachi_muchenik Забавно конечно, как вы мне в комментариях, в точности на такой-же код, написали мол это не то, мне надо по другому, а тут вдруг приняли и все супер. Странный вы человек, странный)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы были недостаточно убедительны :) Но и комментарий - это не ответ.

Comment: Да меня ответ особо не беспокоит) Просто позабавило то, что 2 одинаковых кода, и так по разному восприняты человеком)